# Negation of "and" statements: a and b

Tags: logic

Is it correct?

$\neg$(a and b)=(not a) or (not b)

What ruleset can i look up for negations? Especially for  "all", "if, then" statements.

Comment: That is correct. Quatifiers, when negated change to the other,  ex $\forall$ becomes $\exists$.  If P, the Q is equivalent to $\lnot$ P $\lor$ Q. You can use the negation of that to obtain the negation of the implication (if, then).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, that's called [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). [This site](https://web.archive.org/web/20161123081932/http://www.regentsprep.org/regents/math/geometry/GP1/negatecompound.htm) has more rules about negations of logical connectives and [this PDF](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~aloveles/Math300Summer2011/m300Quantifiers.pdf) should help you with negation of universal and existential quantifiers.

Comment: The site was very helpful! Thanks